# Recalculate div height after html insertion

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div "track-panel" that contains another div "summaries" that is blank at first.

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css';
#track-panel { border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<div id="track-panel">
  <section class="summary">
    <div class="clearfix">Foo</div>
    <div class="col-md-12" id="summaries"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

However, at some point I insert some text into "summaries" and it is displayed OUTSIDE "track-panel".

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css';
#track-panel { border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<div id="track-panel">
  <section class="summary">
    <div class="clearfix">Foo</div>
    <div class="col-md-12" id="summaries">Bar</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have css?
Or a working example?

Comment: I just added a working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `.col-md-12` are floated if the document has a minimum width of 992px. However, you don't clear the float.

You don't need to float it, so just remove the class.

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css';
#track-panel {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="track-panel">
  <section class="summary">
    <div class="clearfix">Foo</div>
    <div id="summaries">Bar</div>
  </section>
</div>
```